# React Styled Component's CSS method optimization

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

#### Which is more optimized and why?

I hear that the `css` method from Styled-component is pretty expensive but I'm wondering if the multiple nested  `${(prop) => {}}` is more expensive than the single fn with the `css` method used inside.

**Approach 1**

```
const Foo = styled.div`
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  width: ${(props) => props.size};
  height: ${(props) => props.size};
  color: ${(props) => props.bgColor};
  background-color: ${(props) => props.bgColor};
`;
```

vs

**Approach 2**

```
const Bar = styled.div`
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  ${(props) => {
    return css`
      width: ${props.size};
      height: ${props.size};
      color: ${props.bgColor};
      background-color: ${props.bgColor};
    `;
  }}
`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance difference should be negligible. The only optimization Styled Components would make is if your styles were static (with no interpolations).

Note that `styled.div` or any other of the Styled CSS methods already do the same work as `css`. And these methods accept functions as arguments (instead of interpolated strings). So you can take it a step further and do this:

```
const Baz = styled.div((props) => css`
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  width: ${props.size};
  height: ${props.size};
  color: ${props.bgColor};
  background-color: ${props.bgColor};
`);
```